# Search container column jsp not working in liferay

Tags: search, liferay, include-path

The Search Container column jsp is not working in liferay.

I am trying to include a jsp within Liferay Search-container of type Document, for displaying search results for a given string.

Below is the snippet of code displaying search-container in the page:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container searchContainer="<%=tagsearchContainer%>"> 
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
            results="<%= hits.toList() %>"
            total="<%= hits.getLength() %>"
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document"
        escapedModel="<%= false %>"
        keyProperty="UID"
        modelVar="document"
        stringKey="<%=true %>"
        >

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp path="/html/search_tag_result_form.jsp"/>

     </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

The search container only displays all fields from the document,all mashed up,without any errors.It does not display the content from the jsp(actually does not include it,and does not throw even if wrong path for jsp is there).Mashed up results are displayed from container-row .

Comment: "Not Working" means? Are you getting some error or getting a blank page or the search results are getting displayed but not properly or the search results are not getting displayed at all?

Comment: The search container is only displaying values of results and total

Comment: Can you check if the code in the included JSP is not throwing any error. Try displaying a simple `html` code in the `search_tag_result_form.jsp` (remove all the other code) and see if that works. If that works then I think there might be some issues with the JSP code.

Comment: No there is no issue/error in included jsp,as I had tried to put html as well as console output in the same..but to no avail.Somehow,even on using non existent path for jsp incluion,it still does not throw any erros

Comment: Even if I add `code`<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text value='<%=document.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_NAME)%>' />`code`,nthing shows up

Comment: I think I got it: just before the last tag `</liferay-ui:search-container>`  write `<liferay-ui:search-iterator />` for the results to appear. I missed it in your code, here is the [explanation](http://www.liferay.com/en/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/SearchContainer) for why to have the `iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the `<liferay-ui:search-iterator />` before the end-tag `</liferay-ui:search-container>`.

This `<liferay-ui:search-iterator />` is used to actually displays the list and the contents inside the `<liferay-ui:search-container-row>` tag.

Here is a good [explanation](http://www.liferay.com/en/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/SearchContainer) for most of the commonly used tags for `search-container`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..was trying it out.but now below the results,total..emptyResultsMessage of search container is being displayed..seems like a trivial issue which is hitting it out badly..Thanks for the quick reply..looking for other possible discrepancies in search container